# Multiple Web Service Calls At Once

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, web-services, asynchronous

We connect with multiple (Around 15-20) third-party web services within our C# Web Application.  We are attempting to find the best way use Multi-Threading or Async to call multiple web services (2-5) at the same time.

What would be the best way to do this?

- Multi Threading
- Async Calls

**It needs the ability to:**

- Connect to Web Service A
- Send the request,
- Connect to Web Service B
- Send the request
- Connect to Web Service C
- Send the request
- Etc...

.. All while waiting for the response for WS A, B, C, etc...

I know I need to be using `IAyncResult`, but i've seen some examples and some use MultiThreading and some do not.  **What would the best way be?**

Comment: Hi, Do you have any code written ?
By the way do you know parallel code it's not asynchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention it in your question, but you've tagged the question with the WCF tag so I'm going to assume that you are trying to make these calls with the WCF client proxy model. If this is not the case, please explain what client technology you *are* using and I can revise my answer.

First, I highly recommend you read this documentation on MSDN: [How to: Call WCF Service Operations Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

First, what you'll be doing is generating your WCF client proxy classes with `SvcUtil.exe`, but specifying an additional flag, `/async` (or simply `/a`), which will generate [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method signatures. Once you've got those client proxies generated you can simply call them like you would any other APM method and supply a callback that will be invoked once the response is available.

Utilizing the APM based WCF signatures will make the outgoing and pending network I/O completely asynchronous which will free up your "main" thread to make the 15-20 calls you need to make concurrently. Also, while the network calls are outstanding, no CPU thread will be wasted.

Now, if you're on .NET 3.5 you'll have to use some kind of synchronization primitive to wait on and signal once each of the callbacks has completed. Unfortunately there's no [`CountdownEvent` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in 3.5 either, but you can just use [`Interlocked::Decrement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z4b2e5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do the countdown and then signal a [`ManualResetEventSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when it reaches 0 (or find a third party library that provides this). If you're on .NET 4.0, you can instead combine the APM model with the [Task-based Asynchronous Programming (TAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) model leveraging [`TaskFactory::FromAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and shove all the `Tasks` into a `List<Task>` and then use [`Task::WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to wait for them all to complete before continuing fwd. Finally if you're on .NET 4.5 you could even combine that gracefully with C#'s `async` keyword and [`Task::WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead and save yourself a lot of manual TPL continuation logic.

Comment: He can create a `BackgroundTasks` and they will allow him to create parallel async call to services.